# Matching text within P tags in HTML

Tags: python, html, regex

I'd like to match the contents within each paragraph in html using a python regular expression. These paragraphs always have BR tags inside them like so:

```
<p class="thisClass">this is nice <br /><br /> isn't it?</p>
```

I'm currently using this pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile('<p class=\"thisClass\">(.*?)<\/p>')
```

Then I'm using:

```
pattern.findall(html)
```

to find all the matches. However, it only matches two of 28 paragraphs I have, and it looks like that's because those two don't have BR tags inside of them and the rest do. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is failing because of the `<br/>` but rather because the paragraph is spread across multiple lines. Use the [DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) mode to fix this:

```
pattern = re.compile('<p class=\"thisClass\">(.*?)<\/p>', re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Or rather you should use the re.DOTALL mode to make the dot also match newlines. http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know it's a newbie mistake ;)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the answer was to include re.S as a flag which allows the "." character to match newlines as well.

```
pattern = re.compile('<p class=\"thisClass\">(.*?)<\/p>', re.S)
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: That's a shortcut to the DOTALL mode